# Navigation (Bullets) very small in custom beamer outer theme

Tags: beamer, formatting, navigation, mini-frames

trying to customize our university theme, I got stuck with the size of the navigation bullets (mini frame style), which are displayed as if scaled to 50% and the same with it's text.
Even though I can change the text size with

```
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}}
```

and the Sections/Subsections are displayed with a nice 9pt font, the bullets remain very small. I inserted the navigation with the following code:

```
\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
```

to the header and use the helvet font - with no strange effect anywhere else though.

Can anybody tell me, how to increase the size of the bullets? Do I have to set the scale factor somewhere?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem: snippets don't really make it easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I tried to make a stripped example, but the answer is already there before I finished.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the definition of the `beamer` templates `mini frame`/`mini frame in current subsection` in [`beamerouterthemedefault.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty) (ll. 21-39), you'll see that the mini frames have a fixed size of 1mm. To change this according to your needs, these templates have to be redefined. This can be done using the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\beamer@miniframeradius
\beamer@miniframeradius=0.05cm
\define@key{beamer@margin}{mini frame radius}{\beamer@miniframeradius=#1\relax}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\beamer@miniframeradius}{\beamer@miniframeradius}}{\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\beamer@miniframeradius}{\beamer@miniframeradius}}{\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\makeatother
```

Input this code in the preamble of your document, i. e. between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`. It defines a new beamer length called `mini frame radius` which controls the size of the mini frames. The space that two mini frames are apart is set with `mini frame size` (which is not a very suitable name, but it's introduced by `beamer` like this). So to enlarge the mini frames, use `\setbeamersize` to change these length, e. g. like this:

```
\setbeamersize{mini frame radius=.07cm,mini frame size=.18cm}
```

#### Minimal test code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\beamer@miniframeradius
\beamer@miniframeradius=0.05cm
\define@key{beamer@margin}{mini frame radius}{\beamer@miniframeradius=#1\relax}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\beamer@miniframeradius}{\beamer@miniframeradius}}{\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}{2\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{\beamer@miniframeradius}{\beamer@miniframeradius}}{\beamer@miniframeradius}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}}
\setbeamersize{mini frame radius=.08cm,mini frame size=.2cm}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}\subsection{subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: headline with enlarged mini frames]